# Stripping a string with a another string shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am running a shell script and I have the following string:

`keystore_location="/mnt/blumeta0/db2/keystore/keystore.p12"` How do I fetch string before `keystore`: i.e `/mnt/blumeta0/db2`. I know how to strip on a single character delimiter and the path before keystore can change. I tried:

```
arrIN=(${keystore_location//\"keystore\"/ })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
arrIN=${keystore_location%%keystore*}
echo $arrIn
/mnt/blumeta0/db2/
```

The `%%` operator removes the longest match, reading from the right side of the string

Note that there are also operators

```
%   --- remove first match from the right side of the string
#   --- remove first match starting from the left side of the string
##  --- remove longest match starting for the left side of the string.
```

IHTH

Comment: @oguzismail ; Doah. see edits (I hope this helps!) . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ keystore_location="/mnt/blumeta0/db2/keystore/keystore.p12"
$ echo "${keystore_location%%/keystore*}"
/mnt/blumeta0/db2
```

`%%/keystore*` removes the longest suffix matching `/keystore*` -which is a glob pattern- from `$keystore_location`.